# React + typescript + propTypes.InferProps throws 'no overload matches this call' when passing props to child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I have this code:

```
import { Route } from 'react-router'

const layoutPropTypes = {
    component: pt.any,
    path: pt.string.isRequired,
    exact: pt.bool,
}

const DashboardLayoutRoute = ({
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}: InferProps<typeof layoutPropTypes>) => {
    const render = (matchProps: any) => (
        <DashboardLayout>
            <Component {...matchProps} />
        </DashboardLayout>
    );

    return (<Route {...rest} render={render} />);
};
```

but TypeScript really doesn't like me passing the `...rest` of the props down to Route:

[image]

There are no problems if I remove the `{...rest}` part. What is wrong here? I don't quite get where it's getting `null` from.